# MYSQL GET_LOCK DB2 Equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, db2

I am attempting to translate a MySql statement into IBM DB2.

I query the MySql Database (using a PDO query)

```
"SELECT GET LOCK(lockname,timeout)"
```

So then I can check if the lock is active, unlock it.

```
if ($result === true)
{
   $this->locker->unlock($lockname);
}
```

Then in "unlock"

```
"SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(lockname);"
```

I can't quite understand how to work with operations as MON_GET_LOCKS.

Comment: Even in MySQL it is an overused function. What operation are you protecting with the locks? Is there some transactional equivalent that can be used instead?

Comment: When migrating, it is an opportunity to simplify :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an attempt to implement some similar approach with the [DBMS_LOCK module](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=modules-dbms-lock-module).
But it seems that it has some implementation bugs in Db2 11.5.7 at least:
The [DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dlm-request-function-requests-lock-based-lock-id-lock-handle) function invocation returns the error below, when you run exactly the same compound statement as in the example at the link above from the 2-nd session, and the same lock is not released in the 1-st session.

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0206N  "TIMEOUT" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

So, if you want to implement something similar, you may do it on your own. It seems, that the algorithm is based on the table `SYSTOOLS.DBMS_LOCK_DET` holding these locks as rows.

Comment: For information: the IBM example mentioned in the docs and in this answer works OK on Db2-LUW v11.5.8.0 .

Comment: At least, the syntax is accepted by the Db2-LUW server 11.5.8.0, it's unclear if the functionality is correct.

Comment: @mao Does the same compound statement really work from a **2-nd** session in 11.5.8?

Comment: If I add a sleep (after the dbms_lock.request), and run the block in 2 concurrent sessions, both accept the syntax, but one gets SQL20540N( -911 from allocate_unique) after a pause. Needs a better test though. Looks like IBM docs for dbms_lock.release() are also broken.

Comment: I  have removed the statement. I found a coders note that It was required for a specific version of the system I am currently changing. Everything is working fine as of now but I'll have to do a lot more steps before I can truly verify if that's a solution.